# How do I hard code a link when I'm calling an attribute? I want the admin user to only enter a relative path but I have a value check if statement

Tags: attributes, link

**How can I simplify this:**

```
<?php echo $attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('pdf_download');
if ($attribute)
{
echo $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()>getValue($_product);
}
?>
```

**Into something like this?**

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getTechpage()) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Technical Documentation') ?></a>
```

Comment: I had more but the wysiwyg cut it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$attribute_value = $_product->getPdfDownload();
```

instead of

```
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('pdf_download');
$attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()>getValue($_product);
```

if you configured the attribute `pdf_download` to be visible on the product page. This is good because you save additional requests to the database. However you might not want the attribute to be listed in the attributes table, just load it to process it by yourself.

For this, you can adjust `template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml` of your theme:

Search for

```
$this->getAdditionalData()
```

and replace with

```
$this->getAdditionalData(array('pdf_download'))
```

The optional parameter of `getAdditionalData` specifies, which loaded attributes to exclude from display.

Comment: Not sure if I understood your actual question but hope that helps to simplify your code anyway.